# Proof of solid angle subtended by a closed surface at any point inside it is $4\pi$?

Tags: integration

I understood the relation between semi vertex angle of a cone and solid angle subtended (i.e. $\Omega=2\pi(1-\cos\theta)$) and I even know how solid angle subtended by a sphere at center is $4\pi$. But I didn’t understand how solid angle subtended by any closed surface (i.e. any irregular 3D figure) at any point inside it is $4\pi$? So is there any proof or we got $4\pi$ by taking approximation?

Comment: This question is perhaps better suited for [math.se].

Comment: When you are inside any closed 3D shape, the shape surrounds you completely no matter which direction you look at.

Comment: $4\pi$ in the context of solid angles means looking out at "all of space". Any ray from the point in any direction must pass through the solid object that encloses it.

Comment: @NinadMunshi ok I understood that way but there is no standard proof for this?

Comment: Why is that not a proof?

Comment: @NinadMunshi I was wondering if there is any mathematical proof but yeah I got it thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a point $P$ inside the closed surface and a sphere surrounding $P$ and you project the surface onto the sphere then it will cover the whole of the sphere. So the solid angle subtended by the surface is the same as the solid angle subtended by the sphere, which is $4 \pi$.